# Read large (+- 50Mb) Json file using Kotlin

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I'm starting to work on a weather app using "openweathermap.org" API, and they provide you with a list of available cities in Json format.

Before i continue with the project, i would like to able to work with the data from this Json file.

The problem is that i get Null whenever i try to read and parse that file.

Here is the code:

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val jsonFileString = getJsonDataFromAsset(applicationContext, "citylist.json")
        Log.i("gabs Data", jsonFileString ?: "Empty Data")
        val gson = Gson()
        val listOfCities = object : TypeToken<List<CityList>>() {}.type
        var cities: List<CityList> = gson.fromJson(jsonFileString, listOfCities)
        cities.forEachIndexed { idx, city -> Log.i("data", "> Item $idx:\n$city") }
    }
}
```

Utils.kt:

```
fun getJsonDataFromAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String? {
    val jsonString: String
    try {
        jsonString = context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
    } catch (ioException: IOException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
    return jsonString
}
```

And the data class (Array of cities data):

```
class CityList : ArrayList<CityList.CityListItem>(){
    data class CityListItem(
        @SerializedName("coord")
        val coord: Coord,
        @SerializedName("country")
        val country: String,
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Double,
        @SerializedName("name")
        val name: String,
        @SerializedName("state")
        val state: String
    ) {
        data class Coord(
            @SerializedName("lat")
            val lat: Double,
            @SerializedName("lon")
            val lon: Double
        )
    }
}
```

And the error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weatherdisplay/com.example.weatherdisplay.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: gson.fromJson(jsonFileString, listOfCities) must not be null.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: gson.fromJson(jsonFileString, listOfCities) must not be null
at com.example.weatherdisplay.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)

Comment: Reading that file and parsing it as JSON are two separate steps here. Does ``jsonFileString`` contain the data, and is it complete and correct? (You're logging it as soon as you've read it.) If it doesn't, your problem is with reading the file. If it does, then your ``gson.fromJson`` call is failing to parse the data. If you look in your logs, it's probably logging a warning if it's failing like that

Answer (score 1):

There were some problems in your code:

1. You were not closing the `BufferedReader`
2. You should not load the file on the Main thread since it will block the UI

I created some sample data corresponding to your data structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Saxony",
    "name": "Dresden",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 0.0,
      "lon": 0.0
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Berlin",
    "name": "Berlin",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 0.0,
      "lon": 0.0
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Baden-Wuerttemberg",
    "name": "Stuttgart",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 0.0,
      "lon": 0.0
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Hessen",
    "name": "Frankfurth",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 0.0,
      "lon": 0.0
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "country": "Germany",
    "state": "Nordrhine-Westphalia",
    "name": "Cologne",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 0.0,
      "lon": 0.0
    }
  }
]
```

Your activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "MyApplication"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                var reader: BufferedReader? = null
                try {
                    // Create a reader and read the file contents
                    reader = assets.open("data.json").bufferedReader()
                    val rawData = reader.use { it.readText() }

                    // Create a Type token that Gson knows how to parse the raw data
                    val cityListType = object : TypeToken<List<City>>() {}.type

                    // Parse the raw data using Gson
                    val data: List<City> = Gson().fromJson(rawData, cityListType)

                    // TODO: Do something with the data
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    // Handle IOException: Gets thrown when the file wasn't found or something similar
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while reading in the data:", e)
                } catch (e: JsonParseException) {
                    // Handle JsonParseException: Gets thrown when there is a problem with the contents of the file
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while reading in the data:", e)
                }
                finally {
                    // Close the reader to release system resources
                    reader?.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Your data structure:

```
data class City(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @SerializedName("country")
    val country: String,

    @SerializedName("state")
    val state: String,

    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

    @SerializedName("coord")
    val coordinate: Coordinate
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "#$id[$name $state $country]@[${coordinate.lat}|${coordinate.lon}]"
    }
}

data class Coordinate(
    @SerializedName("lat")
    val lat: Double,

    @SerializedName("lon")
    val lon: Double
)
```

In the best case you would put the code in which you get the file contents and parse the data in a `ViewModel`, but this would to go beyond the scope for this answer.

Additional information about `ViewModels`: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: If this answer seems correct for you, please mark it as accepted answer.